# I keep getting an error with the JCL code and I don't know why

Tags: jcl

```
//BJCL1804 JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//SORT01 EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN DD DISP,SHR,DSN=ZOS.PUBLIC.DATA(ASCII)
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD SYSIN=*
//SORT DD =(1,1,CH,A)
```

I am trying to use this JCL code and when I use the SUB command, I always get an error. Even after hours of trying and trying, I cannot seem to fix this error. I looked up the error codes from the =SD and I cannot figure out how to fix the issue. The syntax seems to be correct. I just don't understand. Can someone please help me understand why this is causing an error to occur?

Comment: I actually fixed my code to an extent. I now only get 1 error. The error is for the last line. I get the error "IEFC641I"

Comment: IEFC641I Improper subparameter list on the dd statement

Answer (score 1):

You have two things wrong with this:

```
//SORTIN DD DISP,SHR,DSN=ZOS.PUBLIC.DATA(ASCII)
```

This should be "DISP=SHR", not "DISP,SHR"

```
//SYSIN DD SYSIN=*
//SORT DD =(1,1,CH,A)
```

This should be:

```
//SYSIN DD SYSIN=*
SORT FIELDS=(1,1,CH,A)
```

The SYSIN=* is creating an instream temporary dataset with the sort control statements.  Also, I think you need something like "SORT FIELDS=(1,1,CH,A)".

Comment: Good spot on the SHR. You need at least one leading blank for the SORT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
//SYSIN DD SYSIN=*
```

is incorrect syntax.  I believe you want

```
//SYSIN DD *
```

and SORT control statements don't begin with `//`, which is what is causing your IEFC641I error.

The documentation is your friend.

Comment: I corrected what you told me to do. Now... I can an IEFC654I Substitution JCL Error for Line 1 and when I omit the // for the sort on line 9, it seems to work but I am not sure if it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

```
//BJCL1804 JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID
//SORT01 EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSUDUMP DD SYSOUT=*
//SORTIN DD DISP,SHR,DSN=ZOS.PUBLIC.DATA(ASCII)
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN DD SYSIN=*
//SORT DD =(1,1,CH,A)
```

The format of your `JOB` statement should be the same as that for other developers at your site. That "1," *looks* wrong, but since knowing for sure won't help, I'm not going to check. The *JCL Reference* will tell you.

The `SYSPRINT` and `SYSUDUMP` you do not need for a SORT step, although perhaps you are supposed to have them at your site, even though pointless.

As has been pointed out, your `SYSIN DD` is incorrect. You can't just follow the format of a different type of DD statement and hope for the best. it should be:

```
//SYSIND DD *
```

Where the `*` means "instream data" rather than a named dataset.

Sort Control Cards do not start with `//` and do start with at least one blank.

If you are trying to sort a file, it will look something like this:

```
 SORT FIELDS=(1,1,CH,A)
```